# Pandas: Add new columns to DataFrame based on values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame like this:

```
>>> df
    0   1   2
0   2   3   5
1   3   4   7
```

and a function that returns multiple results, like this:

```
def sumprod(x, y, z):
    return x+y+z, x*y*z
```

I want to add new columns, so the result would be:

```
>>> df
    0   1   2  sum  prod
0   2   3   5   10    30
1   3   4   7   14    84
```

I have been successful with functions that returns one result:

```
df["sum"] = p.apply(sum, axis=1)
```

but not if it returns more than one result.

Comment: Is this a general question about how to return multiple columns using your function or is it just to achieve your result? For example: `df['sum'], df['prod'] = df.sum(axis=1), df.prod(axis=1)` gives you what you desire

Comment: It is a general question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to pass the columns of the DataFrame to the function by unpacking the transpose of the array:

```
>>> df['sum'], df['prod'] = sumprod(*df.values.T)
>>> df
   0  1  2  sum  prod
0  2  3  5   10    30
1  3  4  7   14    84
```

`sumprod` returns a tuple of columns and, since Python supports multiple assignment, you can assign them to new column labels as above.

You could write `df['sum'], df['prod'] = sumprod(df[0], df[1], df[2])` to get the same result. This is clearer and is preferable if you need to pass the columns to the function in a particular order. On the other hand, it's a lot more verbose if you have a lot of columns to pass to the function.

Comment: Afterwards, I found that this will only work with functions that can handle arrays. For other cases: `zip(*map(lambda i: func(*i), df.values))`